# Appending one list to another in recursion

Tags: python, recursion

So the question was to find all paths from source to target (https://leetcode.com/problems/all-paths-from-source-to-target/).

```
# code snippet 1

class Solution:
    def allPathsSourceTarget(self, graph: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
        paths = []
        def dfsPath(node):
            if node == len(graph) - 1:
                print(validPath) # line 6
                paths.append(validPath) # line 7
                return paths
            else:
                for n in graph[node]:
                    validPath.append(n)
                    dfsPath(n)
                    validPath.pop()  
        validPath = [0]
        dfsPath(0)
        return paths
```

[image]

```
# code snippet 2

class Solution:
    def allPathsSourceTarget(self, graph: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
        paths = []
        def dfsPath(node):
            if node == len(graph) - 1:
                print(validPath) # line 6
                paths.append(validPath.copy()) # line 7
                return paths
            else:
                for n in graph[node]:
                    validPath.append(n)
                    dfsPath(n)
                    validPath.pop()  
        validPath = [0]
        dfsPath(0)
        return paths
```

[image]

The only change in the above two code snippets is line 7. I've added the print statement in line 6 to show what `validPath` is holding. My question is why appending just `validPath`,  results in a different output than when I append `validPath.copy()` (in line 7).

Comment: from the two screengrabs it looks like the two outputs are the same...

Comment: sorry my mistake @Tanque, fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.copy()` returns a shallow copy of the original list. It returns a new list, does not modify the original list.

so, when you did the `pop()` operation to backtrack on original list, the appended lists in the `paths` are also modified.

you may also use `paths.append(validPath[:])` to get the whole sliced copy of the original list